# Adding int values to ArrayList of int's

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to add int values to an `int[]` as follows.

```
 private ArrayList<int []> read_studioConfig(byte[] buf, int boundary, int offset, int num){

    ArrayList<int []> configs_values = new ArrayList<int[]>();

    int readValues = 0;

    int idx = offset;
    for (int i = 0 ;i < num; i++){
         while(idx < boundary && buf[idx] != 0){
             readValues = i;
             idx ++;
         }
         idx ++;

        configs_values.add(readValues);
    }

    return configs_values;
};
```

But I could not able to do it. I am getting the following error.

> error: no suitable method found for add(int)
>   method Collection.add(int[]) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to int[]) method List.add(int[]) is not applicable (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to int[])**

I am doing a stupid mistake but can't put finger on it. What am I missing here ?

Comment: I think you want: ArrayList<Integer>

Comment: To wit: right now you're creating an array list of `int` arrays.

Comment: @ErnieThomason Changing that solves the problem. But I would like to add values `arraylist of int ` arrays

Comment: Java collections stores objects, not primitive types. To have 2-D arrays, use ```ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arr = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();```

Comment: @DaveNewton yes, I would like to add values to the `arraylist of int` arrays. Is that possible in android ?

Comment: If you want to add arrays, pass arrays, not `int`s.

Comment: @cantona_7 Of course it is--but you can't add an int to a list of int arrays, you need to either add an int array, or add the int to one of the int arrays in the list of int arrays.

Comment: It sounds like `readValues` maybe should have been an`int[]`, not a simple `int` and your loop should be assigning something to `readValues[i]` on every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you're creating a `List` of Arrays of integers, so that is the reason your code is failing.

I'm not sure why you're trying to do due to your code is a little bit dirty, but here you have my suggestion:

Use `List<Integer> configsValue = new ArrayList()` rather than `ArrayList<int[]>`, use interfaces rather than implementations. Also if you don't need to keep direct access even I'd suggest to you to use `LinkedList` instead `ArrayList` because the complexity of adding a new element is O(1) against O(n)

Then your code will work, otherwise if you want to return a `List<int[]>` be aware of you have to create the array before adding it to the collection

Comment: that clears up a lot. I will look into that direction man. Thanks